# Consulta PostgreSQL trazendo mais resultados do que esperado

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Olá, tenho uma situação em um sistema onde preciso encontrar quais as matriculas de alunos estão relacionados à um tutor em uma turma.

As tabelas que eu tenho são:

- `matricula` que contém chave estrangeira com aluno (mat_aln_id) e com turma (mat_tur_id)
- `professor_turma` que contém chave estrangeira com o tutor (prt_pes_id) e com a turma (prt_tur_id)
- `aluno_tutor` que contém chave estrangeira com professor_turma (alt_prt_id) e com o aluno (alt_pes_id)

Em uma turma de 11 alunos, onde apenas 8 estão relacionados a um tutor específico, eu tento buscar as matrículas deles da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(matricula.mat_id)
FROM matricula
INNER JOIN professor_turma ON prt_tur_id = mat_tur_id
INNER JOIN aluno_tutor ON prt_id = alt_prt_id
WHERE prt_tur_id = 92 AND prt_pes_id = 79
```

Esperando receber 8 resultados, mas recebo todos os 11 matriculados.

O exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3f47/2) está aqui, para facilitar o entendimento na prática.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi o erro está no segundo `join`, os campos selecionados não são os indicados.
Tenta assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(matricula.mat_id)
FROM matricula
INNER JOIN professor_turma ON prt_tur_id = mat_tur_id
INNER JOIN aluno_tutor ON at_pes_id = mat_aln_id
WHERE prt_tur_id = 92 AND prt_pes_id = 79
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Estava batendo cabeça e não saia do lugar.